# click on mobile/tablet, hover on other devices (future-proofing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, responsive-design

need an idea, I am stuck in quite the conundrum. I am building a responsive future proof webdesign.

On desktop and similar devices: I have a menu which on hover does a css animation to desplay a description of what hides behind the link and on click navigates to a new page.

On mobile devices: I wish to have a touch-event that triggers the hover (thus desplaying the description) and on touch number 2 it should then navigate to the new page.

the above is doable, but how to do it without checking user-agents, this is my situation. How does one go about future proofing the above.

Any great ideas are more then welcome. :)

Comment: You can just test width. If it is under 600, set a `isMobile` to true and use the variable to test for screen width.
Though why without useragents? Are you exposing sensitive data on the front end? Why do you care?

Comment: sniff the user agent and move on to the next project. There is, sadly, no real future proofing unless it's plain html. and even then...

Comment: Checking the user agent will be a problem in the future for obvious reasons hence I wish to avoid it and checking screen with is kinda a problem as well because of the sheer number of weird sized touch devices out there.

I guess if I could check whether if it is a touch enabled device I would kinda have solved my problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is a horrible idea from a UX point of view. The user shouldn't have to touch a link multiple times to navigate to a new page.

Comment: Whether or not you agree with my UX decisions isn't really the question and hardly relevant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Javascript to add a class on the `touchstart`/`touchend` events. Browsers won't issue these events:

**Javascript:**

```
document.querySelector("#myMenu").addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
    this.classList.add("mobileHovered ");
});
document.querySelector("#myMenu").addEventListener("touchend", function() {
    this.classList.remove("mobileHovered");
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#myMenu:hover,
#myMenu.mobileHovered {
    /* CSS styles */
}
```

Comment: Perfect and simple solution, now why didn't I think of that? :)

thx allot :)